# Zippers in the wild

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, agda, xmonad, zipper

I am currently searching for implementations of [Huet's Zipper](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf) ``in the wild''.

So far, I have found:

- The [agda compiler](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Reduce/Fast.hs) (correct me if I'm wrong) uses the zipper for the eliminator of *call-by-need* evaluations, filling out information as it goes.
- Another instance is used in [XMonad](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/StackSet.hs) to keep [track of the focused workspace and the focused window on each workspace](https://donsbot.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/roll-your-own-window-manager-tracking-focus-with-a-zipper/)

Are there other ways to implement//other implementations of the zipper?

Comment: The stated close reason is "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." -- I don't see how this applies here. The question asks about a particular [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)), and its applications in software. This is neither a request for recommendation, nor is it the kind of question that's likely to attract spam. (This may well be not a great fit, but the stated closure reason does not apply.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR "Or other off site resource". The main point is that there's no definitive way to "answer" the question. It's a request for an annotated list of things, not an answerable problem.

Comment: @Cubic That may well be a valid reason to close the question, but it is *not* the reason currently given. (Also, the question does not ask for *recommendations* (which tend to attract opinionated answers) as you also seem to agree—it asks for examples.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Examples are an "off site resource" in the same vein as books, tools or tutorials.

Comment: I've had trouble with people on S.O. closing questions that are very on-topic to programming and very narrow requests.  The gist of the balk seems to be:  questions that request open-ended lists as the answer are forbidden no matter how well worded, no matter how hardcore on-topic, no matter how precisely worded, no matter how narrow in scope, no matter how not-an-opinion-at-all.  The critiques demand that a question evoke a single answer, not an open ended list of factual answers.

Comment: As a single answer to the now-closed question, an open-source implementation of Huet's zipper is at http://stanch.github.io/zipper which might also give insight which apps utilize this library productively.  OP is a valid question that should be allowed on S.O. and here in this comment I have provided a valid answer as well.